# numpy loadtext returns 0-d array for single line files, annoying?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have the problem, that I wrote code which is using the following numpy calls

```
columnNames = ['A','B','C'];
dt = [(s,np.float64) for s in columnNames];

# load structured unit        
SimData = np.loadtxt( file ,dtype=dt, delimiter="\t", comments='#')
```

If my file contains only one line, then `SimData['A'][0]` does not exist because the command returns a 0-d array, this is somehow annoying?
How can I make my code using indexing which also works for single line files?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the argument `ndmin=1` to force [`loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to return a result that is at least one-dimensional:

```
In [10]: !cat data.tsv
100 200 300

In [11]: a = np.loadtxt('data.tsv', dtype=dt, delimiter='\t', ndmin=1)

In [12]: a.shape
Out[12]: (1,)

In [13]: a
Out[13]: 
array([(100.0, 200.0, 300.0)], 
      dtype=[('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8')])
```